# How to select last of a selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a group of buttons that should have a rounded border only on the first button and last element. In-between buttons should have none. This works fine.

Now I want to add in a text field that should do the same. It should have a rounded border if it's the first or last, otherwise none.

I use `INPUT` for text fields and `BUTTON` for my buttons, so how can I select elements that are the last of either **without** using `:last-child`.

`:last-of-type` does not work because they are of different types. `:last-child` does not work because I may have other siblings (such as a dropdown menu). I'd prefer not to assign more classes because my markup is long enough as it is.

My current:

```
BUTTON:last-of-type, 
INPUT:last-of-type { 
    /* Corners */ 
}
```

What I'd like:

```
BUTTON:last-of(BUTTON, INPUT), 
INPUT:last-of(BUTTON, INPUT) { 
    /* Corners */ 
}
```

Some example markup:

```
<div class="group">
    <label>Controls:</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

Is there a way or should I seek an alternative?

Comment: Yep that's what Mr. Alien has suggested in his answer.

Comment: Indeed, what you're asking isn't currently possible with selectors. In Selectors 4 this might be available with `BUTTON:nth-last-match(1 of BUTTON, INPUT), INPUT:nth-last-match(1 of BUTTON, INPUT)` (or, more simply, `:nth-last-match(1 of BUTTON, INPUT)`), but who knows when it'll reach implementation... maybe in the next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about binding these fields in a separate container?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KaycZ/)

```
.wrap, .wrap2 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.wrap input[type=text], .wrap input[type=button] {
    display: block;
}

.wrap input[type=button]:first-of-type,
.wrap input[type=button]:last-of-type, 
.wrap2 input[type=text]:first-of-type,
.wrap2 input[type=text]:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

---

According to your edit

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/KaycZ/1/)

```
div:first-of-type input[type=text], 
div:first-of-type button,
div:last-of-type input[type=text],
div:last-of-type button {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

As you edited your question, and provided the actual markup you are using, I've used 4 selectors which will match in such a way that it will apply the styles to your textbox and button which are in the first group and last group

---

As you commented, if you don't wish to use extra markup, than it would be better to use classes defined to the items you want to style, this will not only prevent using complicated selectors but will also ease up things for you and will be cross browser as well. But as I provided, solution 2 goes very well as per your needs.

Comment: If by bind you mean change the element types, I don't want to. There are reasons for using `BUTTON` over `INPUT` and the solution I seek shouldn't worry about element types.

Comment: @Jazza provided solution 2

Comment: So sub-dividing the group? It would produce extra markup, but it might have to do. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### If you know whether it is a mixed group or not

If you know ahead of time that the group contains both `button` and `input` elements, or that it does not (even if dynamically generated, as long as the dynamic script "knows"), then setting one extra class on the `.group` element can set up a filter to still use `:last-of-type` as your selector.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Njvjk/26/)**

*CSS*

```
.group.mixed input:last-of-type ~ button:last-of-type,
.group.mixed button:last-of-type ~ input:last-of-type,
.group.unmixed input:last-of-type,
.group.unmixed button:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}
```